# zgeev giving eigenvectors which are not orthogonal

Tags: fortran, lapack

I try to  diagonalize a matrix using zgeev and it giving correct eigenvalues but the eigenvectors are not orthogonal.

```
program complex_diagonalization 
implicit none
integer,parameter :: N=3
integer::i,j
integer,parameter :: LDA=N,LDVL=N,LDVR=N
real(kind=8),parameter::q=dsqrt(2.0d0),q1=1.0d0/q
integer,parameter :: LWMAX=1000
integer :: INFO,LWORK
real(kind=8) :: RWORK(2*N)
complex(kind=8) :: B(LDA,N),VL(LDVL,N),VR(LDVR,N),W(N),WORK(LWMAX)
external::zgeev
!matrix defining
B(1,1)=0.0d0;B(1,2)=-q1;B(1,3)=-q1
B(2,1)=-q1;B(2,2)=0.50d0;B(2,3)=-0.50d0
B(3,1)=-q1;B(3,2)=-0.5d0;B(3,3)=0.50d0  
LWORK=-1
 CALL ZGEEV('Vectors','Vectors',N,B,LDA,W,VL,LDVL,VR,LDVR,WORK,LWORK,RWORK,INFO)
LWORK=MIN(LWMAX,INT(WORK(1)))
CALL ZGEEV('Vectors','Vectors',N,B,LDA,W,VL,LDVL,VR,LDVR,WORK,LWORK,RWORK,INFO)

IF( INFO.GT.0 ) THEN
 WRITE(*,*)'The algorithm failed to compute eigenvalues.'
 STOP
END IF
!eigenvalues
do i=1,N
WRITE(*,*)W(i)
enddo

!eigenvectors
do i=1,N
WRITE(*,*)(VR(i,j),j=1,N)
ENDDO

end
```

and the result I am getting are this:
eigenvalues:

```
( 0.99999999999999978,0.0000000000000000)
(-0.99999999999999978,0.0000000000000000)
( 0.99999999999999978,0.0000000000000000)
```

eigenvectors

```
 (0.70710678118654746,0.0000000000000000)
 (-0.50000000000000000,0.0000000000000000)
 (-0.50000000000000000,0.0000000000000000)


 (0.70710678118654746,0.0000000000000000)
(0.50000000000000000,0.0000000000000000)
 (0.50000000000000000,0.0000000000000000)

(-0.11982367636731203,0.0000000000000000)
( 0.78160853028734012,0.0000000000000000)
(-0.61215226207528295,0.0000000000000000)
```

you can see that the third eigenvector is not orthogonal with one of the two eigenvectors. What I am expecting is that in the third eigenvector first entry should be zero and second entry will be minus of third entry and because it's a unit vector it will be 0.707.

Comment: If you use `d` in `1.d0` and `dsqrt` (but `sqrt` is perfectly sufficient), I would use `double precision` and `double complex` or `real(kind(1.d0))`. `real(kind=8)` and `complex(kind=8)` is similarly long, but not portable (http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/fortran/939/data-types/4390/precision-of-floating-point-numbers#t=201702070914229986179)

Comment: I don't think that will be a problem,I am getting correct eigenvalues and first two eigenvectors also seems to be correct,but the third one because of degeneracy of eigenvalues it is not orthogonal to others but its still a eigenvector of given matrix with eigenvalue 1.

Comment: No, it is not causing the error. I never said that. But it is not nice and may cause a problem some day on a different compiler...

Comment: Why do you expect the eigenvectors as computed by the machine to be orthogonal? By using the general solver, zgeev, you haven't given the library any hint that that matrix is hermitian, and so no hint that even for the degenerate case you expect this orthogonality. What happens if you modify the code to use zheev?

Comment: I thought they will do Gram-Schimidt orthogonalization process. Is there is any solver in Lapack that will give orthogonal vectors for a general complex matrix?

Comment: "1) LAPACK ZHEEV guarantees numerical orthogonality of the eigenvectors, this is 
a Hermitian eigensolver,

2) LAPACK ZGEEV does not guarantee it, this is a non-Hermitian eigensolver, "http://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-forum/archives/lapack/msg01352.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A real symmetric matrix has three orthogonal eigenvectors if the three eigenvalues are unique. Only the eigenvectors corresponding to distinct eigenvalues have tobe orthogonal. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1368948/134138

The Hermitian specialized routine ZHEEV should guarantee orthogonality of the eigenvectors as suggested by Ian Bush. Or in your case you can also consider DSYEV (because your matrix is real).

The situation is well described in this post from LAPACK Forum http://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-forum/archives/lapack/msg01352.html

From the documentation:

```
DSYEV:  
*          On exit, if JOBZ = 'V', then if INFO = 0, A contains the
*          orthonormal eigenvectors of the matrix A.

ZHEEV:
*          On exit, if JOBZ = 'V', then if INFO = 0, A contains the
*          orthonormal eigenvectors of the matrix A.
```

Comment: yes,what you said is right. How can I over come this problem so that using lapack the eigenvectors should be orthogonal to each other?any suggestions.

Comment: I am working on a more general problem ,what I give only a particular part of the general problem.So in my case it is possible that matrix can be non symmetric complex matrix.That is why I used zgeev. so that is why I asked for a solver for general complex matrix.

Comment: But for a non-hermitian complex matrix this is no guarantee that the evecs are orthogonal!

Comment: If you have general matrices, you will have general eigenvectors, I am afraid. You can apply orthogonalization, byt only if the eigenvalues are equal, because then a linear combination is still an eigenvector with the same eigenvalue. And you will have to do that yourself.

Comment: ( Ian Bush) if the matrix is unitary in nature then for different eigenvalues the eigen vectors will be orthogonal.

Comment: But that is a special case and you need software which knows about that and employs that.